# Broke Gnome Shell while trying to add a substitute themes folder-- now computer boots to a black screen,

Tags: boot, unity, gnome

I'm not really thinking in whole sentences right now, so I'll just break this problem down by sections. Let's avoid laughing at my stupid error and focus on fixing the problem too. And it WAS a stupid error. Fortunately I backed up my critical files before attempting.

**How it happened:** Was attempting to replace the “themes” folder in Gnome-Shell. Original folder renamed “themes-original”, new folder (with themes inside) given the name of the original folder and moved into the directory.

**Result**: Gnome-Shell went crazy. Attempted logout via tty1 which was unsuccessful. Force shut down pc as the whole thing had locked up, and was on the fast lane to nowhere.

**Problem**: machine will no longer fully boot. When attempting to boot, will clear the Ubuntu logo, but after that is simply a black screen. Tty1 menu CAN be reached, but booting into unity, kde-plasma, or lxde (all are installed) from tty1 seems fruitless as of current writing.

**Furthermore**: using a bootable usb drive is not turning out any decent results. Can use the bios to attempt to boot via usb, but each time the computer insists the drive is not valid and knocks me back to square one.

**What I need:** Preferably some other way of using TTY1 to force another desktop environment, or, a way of reinstalling Gnome-Shell so that it will work again (possibly by telling it to look in the renamed folder with the original theme?).

**EDIT 4/3/2015**
At this point, I am ready to simply wipe Gnome Shell completely. If I do this from TTY1 via
`sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell`, how can I get the `startx` to denote a different (read: ANY) desktop to load?

Comment: did you try to re-install gnome-shell along with ubuntu-desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is a problem solved.

Seeing as I hate it when people just go "PROBLEM SOLVED" in a forum leaving me wondering how they did it, I will elaborate for anyone who cares to know.

I ran `sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell` in TTY1 to remove gnome-shell, then followed up with `killall -u username`.

From what I understand, it was a bit like trying to unlock your door by throwing a nuclear bomb at it, but it successfully forced me back to the splash screen with no gnome-shell option, and Unity loaded safely and reliably.

I restarted (somewhat nervously) to see if it stuck. It did.

I'm giving this solution a tentative thumbs up, even if it was a little inelegant.